# Trying to supply LT8253 from AC source

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, rectifier

I need to design a 50W USB-PD circuit. TheLT8253 is a DC-DC converter supplied by 24V DC. This circuit must be supplied by a 230V 50Hz AC source. I tried to design a basic AC-DC converter using an LM317  rated for 24V output. The circuit is simulated and the results can be seen in the pictures. 24V output should be fixed 24V. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: *When C2 and C12 is removed, circuit is not working. How to fix this problem?* <--your circuit needs C2 and C12 so, don't remove them.

Comment: There is a semantic error in the text. I know that you mentioned. The green colored wave is output as you can see. After a time, this wave should be fixed at 20V 2.5A. And this circuit can operate when the oscillation is continuous (red wave). This is the problem.

Comment: This won’t work. Buy a 24 V power supply?

Comment: _"The circuit is simulated and the results can be seen in the pictures."_ You've removed the pictures. Why?

Comment: Sorry, but pictures are seen in google searches and I do not want it to be seen. Uninstalling LM317 fixed it.

Comment: @FurkanAdıgüzel I don't usually ask this, but your comment implies that you followed my advice, so if my answer was the solution to the problem you can mark it as accepted and that will let people viewing this in the future know what worked without having to read all the comments.

Answer (score 3):

An LM317 isn't going to be able to supply enough power for you to get 50 W, it would need to supply over 2 A, and it's only rated at 1.5 A.
Not only that, it doesn't look like you're giving it enough input voltage for 24 V out, your schematic shows the source as 22.6 VAC, it should need to be more like 30 to 35 VAC. Also, using a linear pre-regulator at least partially defeats one of the main reasons for using a switcher, efficiency.

That said, you shouldn't need it anyway. The LT8253 has an input voltage range of 4 to 40 V, so you should be able to just filter the rectified voltage and use that as the input.